# How does amiloride increase calcium reabsorption in the kidneys?

Tags: side-effects, renal, diuretics, mechanism-of-action

Amiloride is a potassium-sparing diuretic that acts on the distal convoluted tubule and collecting ducts to inhibit ENaC channels. I found studies that show that this drug [increases calcium reabsorption dependent on luminal pH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1579546), but what is the mechanism behind this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding calcium transport in the kidney:

> In contrast with the proximal tubule and the thick ascending limb of
>   the loop of Henle, the distal tubule reabsorbs calcium exclusively via
>   the transcellular route.

[image]

See also: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4491294/

Also, calcium availability in blood (and hence for filtration in the kidney) is dependent on pH - higher pH will increase binding of calcium to albumine (this is happens e. g.  in plasmapheresis when EDTA is added to your blood to prevent coagulation outside of your body); see also: https://www.kidney-international.org/article/S0085-2538(15)57007-5/pdf

> In the distal convoluted tubule (DCT) and connecting tubule (CNT),
>   acidosis effects the expression of TRPV5, but also the luminal H+
>   concentration has direct effects on TRPV5 activity (H+ inhibits).
>
> Consequently, bicarbonaturia, by increasing luminal pH increases TRPV5
>   activity. There is debate as to whether there is significant calcium
>   reabsorption from the collecting duct. However, α intercalated cells
>   in this segment, when unable to secrete protons such as with dRTA,
>   will fail to acidify the urine altering the solubility of calcium
>   salts. In the proximal tubule, a high pH inhibits citrate reabsorption
>   (as observed in pRTA).
>
> Patients with dRTA have long been appreciated to also have a disorder
>   of sodium wasting.73 The molecular details of how the vacuolar
>   H+-ATPase in the collecting duct contributes to sodium reabsorption
>   were recently described. In combination with pendrin and Slc4A8, the
>   H+-ATPase mediates thiazide-sensitive sodium reabsorption through the
>   β-intercalated cell under situations of volume depletion.72,88,89
>   Mutations in either disease causing subunits would therefore prevent
>   transcellular sodium reabsorption via this mechanism. Consequently,
>   patients with mutations in the H+-ATPase would be prone to volume
>   contraction and, as has been suggested for mutations in NCC, have
>   increased proximal tubular sodium and consequently calcium
>   reabsorption. Thus, if volume contracted, these patients would further
>   attenuate hypercalciuria induced by metabolic acidosis. However, it
>   should also be noted that volume contraction could exacerbate
>   nephrocalcinosis and nephrolithiasis by decreasing urinary flow
>   resulting in increased urine supersaturation of calcium, phosphate, or
>   oxalate.

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5118493/

Comment: The article you linked helped explain why high urine pH increases calcium absorption, but how does this related to amiloride's effect of increasing calcium reabsorption?

Comment: I assumed that it would be known how amiloride works in general: By blocking the sodium/potassium transport in the DCT. You can read more about this here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6927605

Comment: I see. My understanding now based on the above image is that Inhibiting the Na/K transporter on the basolateral side of DCT also activates the NCX transporter, which increases calcium reabsorption.